sceneContainerStyle in React Native, Expo Not working
sceneContainerStyle in React Native, Expo Not working
In New Expo 52 It is not working:
Type '{ children: Element[]; screenOptions: { headerShown: false; tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true; tabBarActiveTintColor: string; tabBarInactiveTintColor: string; tabBarLabelStyle: { fontFamily: string; fontSize: number; paddingBottom: number; textTransform: "capitalize"; }; tabBarStyle: { ...; }; sceneStyle: { ...; }; }; scen...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Omit<(DefaultNavigatorOptions<ParamListBase, string | undefined, TabNavigationState, BottomTabNavigationOptions, BottomTabNavigationEventMap, BottomTabNavigationProp<...>> & DefaultRouterOptions<...>) & { ...; } & BottomTabNavigationConfig, "children" | ... 6 more ... | "UNS...'.
Property 'sceneContainerStyle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<Omit<(DefaultNavigatorOptions<ParamListBase, string | undefined, TabNavigationState, BottomTabNavigationOptions, BottomTabNavigationEventMap, BottomTabNavigationProp<...>> & DefaultRouterOptions<...>) & { ...; } & BottomTabNavigationConfig, "children" | ... 6 more ... | "UNS...'.ts(2322)

Question needs more information

Please check How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example to make better question where the community could answer
